Access log file not created in Docker container for Spring Boot application
I have a Spring-Boot application that does not create an access log file of the embedded Tomcat server while running inside a docker container. But when run outside of the container it does create a file.
Iam using a custom log configuration:
@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> connectorCustomizer(final AccessLogProperties accessLogProperties) {
        return tomcat -> {
            final JsonAccessLogValve logValve = new JsonAccessLogValve();
            logValve.setEnabled(accessLogProperties.isEnabled());
            logValve.setBuffered(accessLogProperties.isBuffered());
            logValve.setRenameOnRotate(accessLogProperties.isRenameOnRotate());
            logValve.setRotatable(accessLogProperties.isRotate());
            logValve.setPrefix(accessLogProperties.getPrefix());
            logValve.setSuffix(accessLogProperties.getSuffix());
            logValve.setPattern(accessLogProperties.getPattern());
            tomcat.addContextValves(logValve);
        };
    }
}

The properties are configured in my application.yml and made available through: AccessLogProperties.class
...
    json-access-log:
      enabled: true
      buffered: false
      pattern: "%{yyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ}t %I %l %u %a %r %q %s (%D ms) %{Authorization}i"
      rename-on-rotate: true
      rotate: true
      prefix: chalkup-${ACTIVE_APP_ENVIRONMENT}
      suffix: .access
...

locally a file is created in the root of my project under ./logs and there a file chalkup-local.access is created and appended with info.
sofar running in intellij results in the access file I need.
When I run the app in a docker container. No file is created:
docker config:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-alpine
ADD ./target/chalkup-*.jar chalkup.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/chalkup.jar"]

  chalk-up:
    container_name: chalk-up
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    environment:
      ACTIVE_APP_ENVIRONMENT: test
    entrypoint:
      - java
      - -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:5005,server=y,suspend=n
      - -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
      - -jar
      - /chalkup.jar
      - -Dspring.profiles.active=local
    volumes:
      - /tmp/logs:/logs
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    depends_on:
      - wiremock

But when I look in the /logs dir in the running container. I only see the regular logfile but NOT the access log file
Changed the basedir, no success
changed read/write permissions in the container. No success
configured the regular access log
server:
tomcat:
basedir: .
accesslog:
enabled: true
But this one also does not appear in the container, while it does when running outside the container
Update:
For now I have build a workaround.
I have extended the JsonAccessLogValve class and overridden the log method. In this log method I simply write the message content to the sl4j log.

Could it be a mixup between ./logs and /logs?

Based upon your comment I tried several options. A basepath other than . and fixed (/tmp for example).
A fixed directory for the LogValue
And some variations in between.
All of them work locally but none work when the app is run inside the container
The workdir in the container is / (Ive checked)
Also the volume mapping should solve the "readonly" bit of the container filesystem
